# Possible Javascript numerical bug

Tags: javascript, numerical

This code snippet:

```
Math.pow(10,20)+20000 == Math.pow(10,20) + 10000
```

evaluates to true. Is this a JS bug?

Comment: no, this is IEEE floating point.

Comment: Check this http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The *slightest* search would tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Javascript uses *floating point* numbers to represent large values, and the value 10<sup>20</sup> exceeds the *precision* of the floating point numbers. When you add a relatively tiny value such as 20000 or 10000 to the result, the resulting sums are indistinguishable.

Comment: 10^20 doesn't exceed the precision of FP numbers, what is at play here is the fact that floating point numbers are not evenly distributed (they become more and more sparse as their magnitude grows).